# ArcGIS Pro 'Convert Labels to Annotation' ignores page query

Tags: arcgis-pro, annotation, map-series, page-query

In ArcGIS Pro, I'm using a map series.  I wish to use labels for one of the layers which also has a Page Query for the map series.  I want to convert the labels to annotations, with a different group of annotations for each page in the map series.  This ensures that the labels are scaled appropriately for each page, and I can add a field to each annotation group and set the values to suit each page in the map series.  Then I can merge all of the annotation groups into a single annotation group and set a page query on it so that the annotations only appear for the relevant page in the map series.

This all works fine.  Except that...

When I 'Convert Labels to Annotations', it ignores the existing page query on that layer and produces annotations for all features that are within the extent of that page.  Some pages have an extent that overlaps with other pages, but the page query only shows the features that are relevant to that page.  It also only shows the labels that are relevant to that page.  However, if I then convert those labels to annotations, it creates annotations for ALL features covered by that page's extent, including those that are not relevant to that page!

Is there any way to get the 'Convert Labels to Annotations' to honour the page query?

(As a work-around, I could manually set a definition query on the layer for each page before running 'Convert Labels to Annotation' for each page.  But there are a lot of pages, and I'd like to avoid that if possible.)

Comment: So the page query on the annotation layer is failing when you create the annotation not when you display it?

Comment: @danak - yes, that is correct.  When displaying as labels (not annotations) it works fine.  But the page query is ignored when converting labels to annotations.  It's unclear if that is intentional behaviour or otherwise.  But it is not what I want.

Comment: Could you page query the done annotation? Maybe add a field to the annotation to match the page query fiel.d.

Comment: @danak - yes, that is actually the goal.  But in order to populate the added field, I have to create the annotations separately for each page, so that I know which ones belong to that page.  And that's the whole problem... when I try to generate the annotations only for one page, I'm also getting annotations that don't belong to that page.